# Use empty table in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a new SQL table of two column [Lot_no, Comment] which is empty.

```
|Lot_No|comment|
```

I have another table of two column [Lot_no, Product_Code] which has values.

```
|Lot_No|Product_Code|
|1     |2304|
|2     |2307|
|3     |2317|
|4     |2308|
```

---

Problem:

1. I want to create a SQL query where I retrieve `[Lot_No|Product_Code|Comment]` for some  `[Lot_No]`  but since no data is available for comment in first table it should return null in comment retrieved column.
2. Later I want to insert new row of Lot_No and comment in that empty table.
   How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` should do the trick.  Perhaps something like this:

```
Select A.Lot_No
      ,A.Product_Code
      ,B.Comment
 From  YourTable A
 Left Join YourCommentTable B
  on  A.Lot_No = B.Lot_No
 Where A.Lot_No = 3 -- for example
```

For the Insert

```
Insert Into YourCommentTable (Lot_No,Comment) values (4,'Some new comment')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot as it is working. Can you please help me with older syntax of left join in the above query as my most query has older syntax of join and it will be confusing if i use ANSI syntax.

Comment: Can you please help me with older syntax of left join in the above query as my most query has older syntax of join and it will be confusing if i use ANSI syntax

Comment: @SauravSingh What do you mean by "older syntax"? There is nothing old about a "left join" and as we can't see your queries which you refer to, we cannot advise you on the,.

Answer (score -1):

I assume by 'older syntax' you mean the old pre-ansi syntax. Try this:

```
Select A.Lot_No
      ,A.Product_Code
      ,B.Comment
From YourTable A, YourCommentTable B
Where A.Lot_No = 3 -- for example 
And A.Lot_No *= B.Lot_No
```